How do I query firestore data that is inside collections in said document?
I am trying to run a query to see if a user's document contains a product ID inside of the document but the problem is that the product ID is stored within its own dropdown collection and not in the first data group, so what I need to do is reach down but the problem is that there can be more than one product like this that all have autogenerating id's when they are created. I am trying to query this to make sure the user has purchased the product before displaying content on it in a v-if statement in vue.

As you can see there are multiple documents within the payments collection and the product I am after is first under items and then under price before I can get there, ordinarily I would just navigate right down to the product but I can't since the payments collection documents autogenerate and have autogenerating ids.
What I have tried doing is this below.
<script>
import { projectFirestore } from '../../Firebase/Config'
import PriceSelection1 from "./CowgirlVid/PriceSelection1.vue";
import SubscribedAccountSignup1 from "./CowgirlVid/SubscribedAccountSighnup1.vue";
import { firebaseAuth } from "../../Firebase/firebase";
import { ref } from 'vue'
import {
  getFirestore,
  collection,
  query,
  where,
  getDocs,
} from "firebase/firestore";
export default {
    components: {
    PriceSelection1,
    SubscribedAccountSignup1
  },
  data() {
    return {
      isLoading: false,
      Purchased2: null,
    };
  },

  mounted() {
    this.fetchSubscription();
  },

  methods: {
    async fetchSubscription() {
      this.isLoading = true;
      const db = getFirestore();
      const subsRef = collection(
        db,
        "Subscribed", firebaseAuth.currentUser.uid, "payments"
      );
      const subsQuery = query(
        subsRef, 
        where("product", "==", "prod_QIRNX4klvLTfKe" )
      );

      this.subscription = await getDocs(subsQuery)
        .then((sub) => 
            sub.docs.length > 0 ? sub.docs[0].data() : null);

      this.isLoading = false;
    },
  },

Ignore the subscription it doesn't mean a subscription we are dealing with stripe one time products that I am trying to get the id off I know that subscription products have the id on the top level but these are unfortunately one time products which do not.
I have also tried using collectionGroup queries from the firebase docs like below
  methods: {
    async fetchSubscription() {
      this.isLoading = true;
      const db = getFirestore();
      const subsRef = collection(
        db,
        "Subscribed", firebaseAuth.currentUser.uid, "payments"
      );
      const subsQuery = query(collectionGroup(
        subsRef, "items", "price" ),
        where("product", "==", "prod_QIRNX4klvLTfKe" )
      );

      this.subscription = await getDocs(subsQuery)
        .then((sub) => 
            sub.docs.length > 0 ? sub.docs[0].data() : null);

      this.isLoading = false;
    },
  },


Yes, I have imported collectionGroup I just haven't included the top of my code in this snippet as it hasn't changed.
Does anyone have any idea how to get the product id by using collectionGroup or some other means? I would greatly appreciate any help.

What shape are you expecting this.subscription to be after your query resolves? Is it the  item that contains the product? Is it the full document that contains the product? (i.e. items array + invoice)

this.subscription is then used as v-if="subscription" Content relating to the product will appear and then I am using v-if="!subscription" inside this div will be the link to take you to the checkout to buy the product.

As far as I can see in your screenshot, the items field is a type array field containing complex objects. Unfortunately, there is no way you can get documents from the "payments" collections based only on a single ID field of an object that exists inside the items array. In other words, you cannot create a query based only on the product ID. To be able to filter the data, you should use the entire object, and not only some partial data. The object should contain values for all the fields.
If you cannot use the entire object to create the filtering, then the only option that you have is to create an array that can hold only the IDs of the products. In the end, you can filter the documents in the collection, using the array contains operator.

Thank you for responding to my question, Sorry but I am not sure I understand what you mean by use the entire object, as the object will have different values every other time it is generated except the product ID which I was trying to get.  Sorry is it possible for you to give me an example so I can understand what you mean?

@Epimetheus14 Alex is suggesting to create a string array called "products" (or similar), at the same level as items and invoice in your payment document. This array should contain all product IDs mentioned in that payment. You then can query for a particular product using where("products", "array-contains", someProductId). Once you know which documents have that product, you can then grab the full document and do whatever you want with it.

Okay thankyou that makes sense now, I will have to see if there is a way to add this when the stripe checkout completes.

Thank you for the advice about creating a new array with the products in, I have now added this on the price selection page which takes me to the stripe checkout and I have added a line at the end when the success Url gets attached it adds the product to the product array.
  async createSub() {
      this.isLoading = true;
      const db = getFirestore();
      const collectionRef = collection(
        db,
        "Subscribed",
        firebaseAuth.currentUser.uid,
        "checkout_sessions"
      );
      const collectionRef2 = collection(
        db,
        "Subscribed",
        firebaseAuth.currentUser.uid,
        "payments"
      );

      const docRef = await addDoc(collectionRef, {
        mode: "payment",
        price: this.selectedPrice,
        success_url: window.location.href,
        cancel_url: window.location.href,
        
      });

      onSnapshot(docRef, (snap) => {
        const { error, url } = snap.data();
        if (error) {
          console.error(`An error occured: ${error.message}`);
          
          this.isLoading = false;
        }

        if (url) {
          window.location.assign(url);
          addDoc(collectionRef2, {
          product:"prod_QIRNX4klvLTfKe",
          })

        }
       
      });
    },
  },
};

So now the code I had shown before works and it is able to find the product id and then display what I want.

